# Parse server open source Android Twitter Login is not working

Tags: java, android, twitter, parse-platform

I am developing Android Application with Parse Server. Right now, the normal login system and Facebook login system is working well. However, Twitter login is not working.

Here is my code:

```
twitterLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(MainActivity.this, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                if (user == null) {
                    Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
                } else if (user.isNew()) {
                    Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Twitter!");
                } else {
                    Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Twitter!");
                }
            }
        });

    }
});

ParseTwitterUtils.initialize("","");
```

I just copy from parse server doc.

[the gif when i login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWf3e.gif)
Sometime, it gives this log: 
Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login

[the gif when twitter pop up and login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4uAq.gif)
it doesn't give any log. so i don't think it is working

Comment: Hide your twitter keys!!

Comment: No problem! Did you check the answer I posted? If it worked, please mark it as "accepted answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue!  Seems that parse server doesn't have twitter integration by default. I'm looking into it!

Here is the stack trace I'm getting:

```
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: 
at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:279)
at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:303)
at com.parse.ParseRESTUserCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTUserCommand.java:126)
at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:137)
at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:133)
at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:715)
at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:726)
at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:818)
at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:806)
at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**Edit:** 
I found the solution, in your parse server you must configure something like this:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed

  oauth: {
   twitter: {
     consumer_key: "xxx", // REQUIRED
     consumer_secret: "xxx" // REQUIRED
   },
   facebook: {
     appIds: "xxxx"
   }
  }

});
```

Check [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/OAuth) and [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) in advanced options.