# Twitter auth configuration missing (ParseTwitterUtils)

Tags: android, twitter, parse-server

Did not get any working solution for integrating Twitter authentication with parse server. I have read almost all the solutions over github and applied it but no luck.More information I have used ParseUI project.

```
https://github.com/parse-community/ParseUI-Android
```

I have used this library provided by parse'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.6' to authenticate user. But no luck. After searching over internet I found some are telling to add following code on index.js page.

```
oauth: {
  twitter: {
  consumer_key: "qweREbUdsfsdfsdfsdfsd4wIg9EX", // REQUIRED
  consumer_secret: "AZrUDjnEVUsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfxcpxBtM0X3" // REQUIRED
  },
  facebook: {
          appIds: "8489456465"
       }
  }
```

After then I am Getting response:

```
04-27 01:53:32.340 16920-17090/app.com.parse.example D/OkHttp: {"code":1,"error":"Twitter auth configuration missing"}
<-- END HTTP (55-byte body)
04-27 01:53:47.148 16920-17113/app.com.parse.example D/OkHttp: {"authData":{"twitter":{"consumer_key":"VdzzbGHfHgFhgFHGf4wIg9EX","auth_token":"157620898-qbODfHyHJKGHGJHGJHGJHGmF38LeJ2cd","screen_name":"blackjack","consumer_secret":"AZrUwerHJGJHGJHGJHGhgjhgZwJopxBtM0X3","id":"1554545698","auth_token_secret":"PK6IgEQMrszxcjhgjhgjhjhJHGrh1Ure8IGbuPX6H"}}}
--> END POST (319-byte body)
04-27 01:53:47.239 16920-17113/app.com.parse.example D/OkHttp: {"code":1,"error":"Twitter auth configuration missing"}
<-- END HTTP (55-byte body)
04-27 01:53:47.255 16920-16920/app.com.parse.example W/ParseLoginFragment: Twitter login failed, exception: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: Twitter auth configuration missing
```

Also got:

```
04-27 16:31:33.705 4998-4998/com.parse.loginsample.basic     W/ParseLoginFragment: Twitter login failed, exception:     com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure
```

Reference answer/discussion didn't solve my problem:

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/973

[Parse server twitter authentication: Twitter auth integrated but unable to create session to use on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500612/parse-server-twitter-authentication-twitter-auth-integrated-but-unable-to-creat)

[Parse server open source Android Twitter Login is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38795931/parse-server-open-source-android-twitter-login-is-not-working?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oauth option is deprecated and will be removed in a future release, please use auth option instead.

> http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#oauth-and-3rd-party-authentication

See change log:

> https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#230

Example:

```
auth: {
  twitter: {
  consumer_key: "qweREbUdsfsdfsdfsdfsd4wIg9EX", // REQUIRED
  consumer_secret: "AZrUDjnEVUsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfxcpxBtM0X3" // REQUIRED
  },
  facebook: {
      appIds: "8489456465"
   }
}
```